# Gitlab Server - how to remove or not expose the url .well-known/openid-configuration?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-omnibus, gitlab-ce

I have a gitlab server hosted on-prem, using the CE version. Recently, our security team requested us to not to expose the url /.well-known/openid-configuration. My question is how do I block this url or how should I configure gitlab so that this url is not exposed?

Comment: There should be nothing in the well-known configuration that is dangerous to expose. Have your security team told you why they don't like it? Or are they just being overly paranoid?

Comment: they said that the url exposes OpenID configuration which could allow different types of hidden oauth attack vectors. and they suggest the server should be configured to prevent such informative files from being exposed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitLab uses NGINX and provides a way to add custom settings in /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb.

Maybe, adding something like this:

`nginx['custom_gitlab_server_config'] = "location ^~ /.well-known/openid-configuration {\n deny all;\n}\n"`

Then, reconfigure gitlab:

`sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure`

See https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#inserting-custom-nginx-settings-into-the-gitlab-server-block

Comment: this works, any visits to the service url will return 403 now. Thank you :)